# Responsive: resize background image in div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm using the code below to display an image as a background in a `div`. How do I resize it?

```
#header {
    height: 255px;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-image: url('../simg/header.png');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try controlling the size of the background by using the `background-size` property.

E.g.:

```
#header {
height: 255px;
-webkit-background-size:50%;
-moz-background-size:50%;
background-size:50%;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-image: url('../simg/header.png');
}
```

This will reduce the background image to exactly half in either dimension.

Comment: Thanks I was using "cover" and that was throwing me off. one other question when I resize the browser how would I set the "height" to auto adjust with the background-size?

Comment: You can use media queries to control the height based on size of the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

try Easy Background Resize .js http://johnpatrickgiven.com/jquery/background-resize/

Comment: I don't think he's looking for JS here.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can try is to set the css

```
background-size:contain;  
width:50%; 
max-height:255px;
```

and let the browser figure out the height which results in it maintaining the aspect ratio.